# how to get individual numbers of a box

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudoku

I'm struggling to get each of the four numbers of a python array contained within a 2x2 into their separate arrays much like a Sudoku grid. Order doesn't matter. I would have tried writing a code or something but my mind has gone blank.

example grid

```
[
    [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
    [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
    [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
```

I want to be able to get it in the form

```
[
    [ 1,  2,  5,  6],
    [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
    [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
    [11, 12, 15, 16]
]
```

Comment: please before downvoting a question, please at least give a good reason. here is someone who wants to learn but the downvotes puts them off this site.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure Python solution. If you are after something more readable consider using NumPy (see below).

```
>>> from itertools import count, chain
>>> 
# create 2x2 blocks of 2x2
>>> c = count(1)
>>> L4D = [[[[next(c) for i in range(2)] for j in range(2)] for k in range(2)] for l in range(2)]
>>> L4D
[[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]], [[[9, 10], [11, 12]], [[13, 14], [15, 16]]]]

# swap middle dimensions
>>> L4D = [zip(*i) for i in L4D]
# next line is not necessary, only here so we can see what's going on
>>> L4D = [list(i) for i in L4D]
>>> L4D
[[([1, 2], [5, 6]), ([3, 4], [7, 8])], [([9, 10], [13, 14]), ([11, 12], [15, 16])]]

# join first two and last two dimensions
>>> result = [list(chain.from_iterable(j)) for j in chain.from_iterable(L4D)]
>>> result
[[1, 2, 5, 6], [3, 4, 7, 8], [9, 10, 13, 14], [11, 12, 15, 16]]
```

If using NumPy is an option this can be simplified. Here are three different possibilities. The first is a direct translation of the pure Python solution:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> np.arange(1, 17).reshape(2, 2, 2, 2).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(4, 4)
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
>>> np.block(list(map(list, np.arange(1, 17).reshape(2, 2, 2, 2))))
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
>>> a = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)
>>> b = np.ones((2, 2), dtype = int)
>>> 4 * np.kron(a, b) + np.kron(b, a) + 1
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my question with a little modification to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/109731/557633)

```
cells = [[] * 4 for x in range(4)]
for row_index, row in enumerate(grid):
    for col_index, col in enumerate(row):
        i = col_index//2 + 2*(row_index//2)
        cells[i].append(col)
```